# Can non brother sisters wish each other Happy Raksha Bandhan?

Tags: belief, philosophy, culture

Can people who are not (and cannot be) brothers and sisters wish each other *Happy Raksha Bandhan* without tying Rakhis?

People like friends, lovers, spouse etc.

Comment: If your question is just about wishing then anybody to anyone can wish just like any other celebration or festival. When it comes to the tying the rakhi then its not necessary to be a brother-sister relation, but its mentally both treating each other as brother and sister. May be my answer is not perfect but in simple words a girl/women can tie rakhi if she treats the other person like brother and same way with the boy/man

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

Raksha Bandhan is not based on any religious scriptures, but from an incident in indian history, symbol of platonic relation.  So long the individuals involved are true to their intentions in core of their heart, it can extend beyond boundaries of blood relation.

Some stories are told on the origins of this raksha bandhan in hindu mythology, however, they do not stand technical scrutiny (Goddess Laxmi & King Bali,  Lord Krishna & Drapaudi).  Mythological instances are possible, however, the symbolic thread wrapping is not.